Should this part be non-restrictive?

The Tim Burton-directed superhero film has multiple mistakes, but a major one happens when Joker and his crew deface paintings at a museum. One of his gang members slaps a painting with his hands that are covered in red paint, but in the next shot, the handprints have disappeared from the artwork.

Source: https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/features/worst-movie-mistakes-ever-films-harry-potter-b2540817.html
Should the bold part be non-restrictive, non-essential because he doesn't have other hands that are not the two hands that are covered in red paint?

Yes.  ... with his hands, which are covered in wet red paint, but ...

Yes, it should be 'which'.
Strictly speaking, 'that' indicates a defining (identifying) clause while 'which' introduces a non-defining (giving additional, parenthetical information) clause. In practice, many native speakers use 'which' for either these days, and some dictionaries acknowledge this; but 'that' is only ever used for defining clauses and your quote, which is wrong, is an example of why not.
"Hands" is plural in your example, so both hands must be covered in paint. Unless this character has more than 2 hands then there is nothing to define - no other hands could be referred to. If it said "his hand (singular) that is covered in paint" then that could be considered correct because it is telling you that only one of his hands was covered in paint and that is the hand he used to touch the painting.
Changing it to 'which' makes the fact his hands were smeared with paint an additional, non-defining piece of information about his hands. This would be completely correct, although in the context of the statement about the handprints it seems to be an important detail. Perhaps this is why the speaker/writer thought it ought to be a defining clause? A better way to phrase it, if they'd thought about it, would have been "(he) slaps a painting with his paint-covered hands".
